# Scraping href which includes ads information

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to count how many ads there are in this website: https://www.lastampa.it/?refresh_ce

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to do this. I would need to extra info within the following:

```
<a id="aw0" target="_blank" href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjssYz5VxTdwhxCBCrbtSi0dfGqGd25s7Ub6CCjsHLqd__OqfDKLyOWi6bKE3CL4XIJ0xDHy3ey-PGjm3_yVqTe0_IZ1g9AsvZmO1u8gciKpEKYMj1TIvl6KPivBuwgpfUDf8g2EvMyCD5r6tQ8Mx6Oa4G4yZoPYxFRN7ieFo7UbMr8FF2k6FL6R2qegawVLKVB5WHVAbwNQu4rVx4GE8KuxowGjcfecOnagp9uAHY2qiDE55lhdGqmXmuIEAK8UdaIKeRr6aBBVCR40LzY4&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzEIRw7NDzCe7&amp;adurl=https://track.adform.net/C/%3Fbn%3D38337867&amp;nm=3&amp;nx=357&amp;ny=-4&amp;mb=2" onfocus="ss('aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onmouseover="ss('aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')"><img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/5262715044200667305" border="0" width="990" height="30" alt="" class="img_ad"></a>
```

i.e. parts containing ads information.

The code that I am using is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get("https://www.lastampa.it/?refresh_ce")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
ads_div = soup.find('div')
if ads_div:
    for link in ads_div.find_all('a'):
        print (link['href'])
```

It does not scrape any information because I am considering the wrong tag/href. How could I get ads information in order to count how many ads there are in that webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about use a regular expression to match "googleads" and count how many you get.

Recursively searching from the body gives you all the links in the whole page. If you want to search in a specific div you can supply parameters such as the class or id that you want to match as a dictionary.
You can filter the links once you obtain them.

```
body = soup.find('body')
if body:
    for link in body.find_all('a'):
        if "ad" in link['href']:
            print (link['href'])
```

When looking at the response that I get, I notice there are no ads at all. This could be because the ads are loaded via some script, which means the ads won't be rendered and requests won't download it. To get around this you can use a webdriver with selenium. That should do the trick.

Comment: I see, @AlpacaJones. Actually, there should be a few there (one in the background and smaller ones within the page. For example, `<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://4b2c241619fddaa6ba32035324851a8b.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-37/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/35012960/lastampa.it/hp/Top1_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true" ....</iframe>`. But I do not know how to get this info using selenium

Comment: Don't forget that the page do not load in all data before yo scrolled to the end of the page..